# NoSuchMethodError: 'int kafka.utils.TestUtils.boundPort(kafka.server.KafkaServer, org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol)'

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, apache-kafka

I am getting below errors while running the junit test cases using embedded kafka

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'int kafka.utils.TestUtils.boundPort(kafka.server.KafkaServer, org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol)'
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'int kafka.utils.TestUtils.boundPort(kafka.server.KafkaServer, org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol)'
```

I am new to Kafka and trying to figure out the compatibility issues

kafka - 2.3.1, kafka_2.11-2.0.1 , scala-library- 2.12.0, spring-kafka-test - 2.5.6.RELEASE

I tried searching for this issue, but i can't find relevent jar.

Comment: You have *Spring* Kafka test, but do you have a Kafka test dependency?

Comment: no i dont have Kafka test dependency

Comment: Kafka clients don't need Scala. What does this mean? "kafka - 2.3.1, kafka_2.11-2.0.1" ; You shouldn't need `kafka-clients` **and** the server `kafka_2..` as a dependency, but if you did, ideally they would be the same version. And if you used a server, it would be an integration test, rather than a unit test with mocks